# An unhandled win32 exception occurred in MyApp.exe

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, mfc, winapi

WinXP used. When I click the default cross icon to close my application. The win form of my application disappeared, but MyApp process still alive in the processes list when I open the task manager window. About 5 seconds later, throw out the unhandled win32 exception error.

Where can I set the break point? I don't know how to debug it. Thanks.

[updated]

**What is the exception received?**

*When I run MyApp.exe(Debug Version). 
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger Window*

An unhandled win32 exception occurred in MyApp.exe[520]
The [520] always changed to different numbers. such as [5904],[304],etc.

Comment: Is your application based on MFC? Does it use multithreading? What is the exception received?

Comment: Yes, MFC based. And multithreading used too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Attach your Vc to the program.
- Enable catch of all exeptions.
- Close your application and see where it stops.

Comment: @Nano HE: On VS2008 you can do this using Debug->Exceptions.. (Ctrl + Alt + E). Check all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

You just run it under your IDE, it will show the location of the exception. If you do not have an IDE; note the address of the exception from the information dialog, look that address up from the MAP file generated with the EXE and try to locate the function...